# Smallest standard compliant object size in C++?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I know the size of an empty class is defined by the standard to be non-zero. It is *usually* 1 byte on most implementations.
But, does the C++ standard specify the minimum possible size of an object?  Is it logical to assume that as per standard the size of an empty class object will be **atleast** 1 byte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The minimum size of an object is zero (§1.8/5). However, complete objects must always have non-zero size, and that size must be at least one.

> Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most derived object shall have a
>   non-zero size and shall occupy one or more bytes of storage. Base
>   class subobjects may have zero size. An object of trivially copyable
>   or standard-layout type (3.9) shall occupy contiguous bytes of
>   storage.

Base class subobjects of empty types can have zero size thanks to what is known as EBCO, the *empty base class optimization*.

Comment: It says _subobjects_. Does that count? I think the key is that a most-derived object shall have _non-zero_ size, which means any complete object must be at least 1 byte wide.

Comment: So `sizeof (object.subobject)` can be 0 if `subobject` is an empty class instance?

Comment: @leemes: I believe you're confusing "subobject" with "member"

Comment: @Lightness subobjects are still objects. The question does not restrict itself to most-derived objects.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Are they? I think that subobjects do not count as objects in the same sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right. In this case: `sizeof(*(EmptySubclass*)this)` => is non-zero, isn't it? How can we treat subobjects as "objects" (instances of the base class)?

Comment: @leemes no. `sizeof` always gives you the size of the type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit same clause, paragraph 2 "Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject (9.2), a base
class subobject (Clause 10), or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object is
called a complete object."

Comment: The standard does appear to call subobjects "objects" and treat them similarly. Still, I'd have thought the intent of the OP was to ask about complete objects.

Comment: Well, in that case the same quote still answers it. Only my fluff may or may not be relevant :P

Comment: Well, make the distinction clearer to the OP and you can have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks. I was meaning to ask about *complete objects* and was looking for the specific *"shall occupy one or more bytes of storage."*.